# How can I make an sql query return a row for every day in a range of dates in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I make an sql query return a row for every day in a range of dates in mysql?

I have a job table that has this kind of structure:

```
job_id  |   station_id  |   start_date  |   end_date    |
--------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
    1   |   1           |   2017-06-01  |   2017-06-02  |
    2   |   2           |   2017-06-01  |   2017-06-03  |
    3   |   1           |   2017-06-02  |   2017-06-04  |
    4   |   4           |   2017-06-01  |   2017-06-02  |
    5   |   2           |   2017-06-04  |   2017-06-05  |
    6   |   1           |   2017-06-06  |   2017-06-08  |
    7   |   3           |   2017-06-01  |   2017-06-02  |
```

and a station table:

```
station_id |    type    |
-----------+------------|
    1      |    1       |
    2      |    1       |
    3      |    2       |
    4      |    2       |
    5      |    2       |
```

If I want to know something like how many station of type 2 were in use on 2017-06-01 I can easily do this:

```
SELECT COUNT(job_id)
FROM jobs
WHERE start_date <= '2017-06-01'
AND  end_date > '2017-06-01'
AND station_id IN (SELECT station_id FROM station WHERE type = 2);
```

This example would tell us that 2 stations (3 and 4) were in use:

```
+-------------+
|COUNT(job_id)|
+-------------+
|           2 |
+-------------+
```

However, ***I would like this to return a row for every day in a range of dates***.

So far I've solved this with a python script that runs the first query multiple times, ***is there a way to do this directly with mysql?***

*EDIT: As requested by user1960808 the expected result for range 2017-06-01 2017-06-03 and type 2 would be this:*

```
+-----------+-------------+
|   date    |COUNT(job_id)|
+-----------+-------------+
|2017-06-01 |   2         |
|2017-06-02 |   0         |
|2017-06-03 |   0         |
+-----------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps the simplest way is to generate the range:

```
select d.dte, count(job_id)
from (select '2017-06-01' as dte union all
      select '2017-06-02' as dte 
     ) d left join
     jobs j
     on j.start_date <= d.dte and j.end_date > d.dte
where j.station_id in (select station_id from station s where s.type = 2)
group by d.dte;
```

If you have lots of dates, this is not the most efficient solution.

Comment: Thank you for your help, this gets me closer to what I need. However, if I understand this correctly, one must write each date separately. I was looking for something that would allow me to specify an initial and a final date and have mysql generate the dates, which is what my current solution using python does. Is that not possible using mysql?

Comment: @user1090729 . . . If you have a `Calendar` table, you can use a subquery to generate the dates.

Comment: I don't have one, but I see how it could help. Do you think that would be the best solution? (I'm assuming a Calendar table is just a regular table that contains a row for every date, if it's something else please correct me)

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
DELIMITER $$

Create Procedure GetJobRunningCount(dStartDate datetime,dEndDate datetime,dType int)
Begin

  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS CountSummary;
  CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE CountSummary(SelectedDate date,Count int);


  While (dStartDate<=dEndDate) do

  insert into CountSummary(SelectedDate,Count)
    SELECT dStartDate,COUNT(1)
FROM jobs jo
inner join station st on(st.station_id=jo.station_id and type=dType )
WHERE start_date <= dStartDate
AND  end_date > dStartDate;


 set dStartDate=Date_add(dStartDate,interval 1 Day);

   End while;

   select * from CountSummary;

END$$
DELIMITER ;

call GetJobRunningCount('2017-06-01','2017-06-08',2)
```

Comment: I'm trying to understand, wouldn't this only work for today?

Comment: I see, I was looking for something where I could specify two dates and it would return a row for every day in the range.

Comment: Then you can use your date instead of date(now()).

Comment: Yes, exactly. But the question is, how to do it for a range of dates, rather than a single date each time.

Comment: Plz send ur output sample.

Comment: I have added an output sample to the bottom of the original question.

Comment: did you check my answer?

Answer (score 0):

If you can create an integer table as mentioned in below url then I think it can be achieved with below query.

https://www.xaprb.com/blog/2005/12/07/the-integers-table/

Query after creating an integer table

```
SELECT job_id,station_id,start_date + INTERVAL i DAY, start_date,end_date
FROM job
INNER JOIN integers
       ON i <= DATEDIFF(end_date,start_date)
AND station_id IN (SELECT station_id FROM station WHERE type = 2);
```